# use the paperclip to upload .torrent file, but get invalid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, activeadmin

I use the paperclip to upload my ".torrent" file in activeadmin, but get the invalid error always.

[image]
my environment is (Mac Os X 10.10.1/ Ubuntu 14.04) + (rails4.1.8) + (paperclip 4.2.1)

this is my log information

[image]

if anyone provide for me a way to allow every types I can finish my work also.

thanks everyone.

there is my appurtenence model and schema

**appurtenence_model.rb**

```
class Appurtenance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :episode
  has_attached_file :file, {
    :url => "/system/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:filename",
    :hash_secret => "longSecretString"
  }
  validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: ["application/x-bittorrent"] }
end
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "appurtenances", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "episode_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "file_file_name"
    t.string   "file_content_type"
    t.integer  "file_file_size"
    t.datetime "file_updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: can you add the model and view where you are using paperclip?

Comment: @DemiMagus I update my model and schema, I don't know where is my mistake, thanks.

Comment: mmm well, the content_type it's ok and there's nothing strange in the model. Maybe the active admin gem has an uploader file too, can you see if it exists? and probable there is a content_type that only allows images or something